# Web server to Android video streaming

Tags: android, video

I want to create an android multimedia application in which my videos will be on the be the web server. I would be thankful for some help or advice on how I would stream the video from the web server, and upload/download my videos to the web server from my Android app.

Comment: so, have you created the sever application  ?  Where were you stuck at the moment ?

Answer (score 0):

An easier method might be to use the Youtube API, then you can host your videos there and just pre-define the videos that are available through your app

It removes the need for the server or server application entirely and lets you focus on android

So when you send your intent to the Youtube player activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, PlayerActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, YOUR_VIDEO_ID)
                startActivity(intent);
```

where YOUR_VIDEO_ID is the id of the video you want to show, in the PlayerActivity you can then read the ID:

```
       @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
            if (!wasRestored) {
              Intent intent = getIntent();
              String videoId = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
                player.cueVideo(videoId);
            }
        }
```

You can find more info on the YouTube API here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/